# node-twig node js - accessing twig vars

Tags: javascript, node.js, twig

I have done everything according to the documentation, and I have tried using a combination of different methods but still to no avail.
I have tried the code below and tried to reference this var in the main file like so :

```
// none of the below worked.
{{ foo ~ context.foo ~ options.foo } }

router.get('/orders', function(req, res) {
    res.render('orders',
        {
            foo: 'bar',
        }
    });
});
```

I cant seem to use the `dump()` function. How would am I be able to use it?

Also I'm trying to do an ordered update with this library but the documentation is very poor. How would I go about instantiating an order object and update?

Answer (score 0):

in a Twig file you would use dump like so:

```
{{ dump(variable) }}
```

In your case you might try:

```
{{ dump(foo) }}
```

You can only call `dump` in a DEV environment, otherwise you will get errors. The rest of your code doesn't make sense to me. It seems like non-standard twig code.

Comment: Hi there. This is the twig for node js. I use it all the time for php with no issues